# java.sql.SQLException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc3.Jdbc3PreparedStatement.setQueryTimeout(int) is not yet implemented

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am working on Spring batch project while connecting to the postgresql database i am getting the bellow error.

> java.sql.SQLException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc3.Jdbc3PreparedStatement.setQueryTimeout(int) is not yet implemented.

How do I fix this out please help me in this.
I am using postgres 9.4-1201-jdbc41 driver version
and Spring jdbc 4.1.4.RELEASE

```
Stack trace
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc3.Jdbc3PreparedStatement.setQueryTimeout(int) is not yet implemented.
    at org.postgresql.Driver.notImplemented(Driver.java:753)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.setQueryTimeout(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:668)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.setQueryTimeout(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1800)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.applyTimeout(DataSourceUtils.java:275)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.applyStatementSettings(JdbcTemplate.java:1399)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:639)
    ... 37 more
]
Execution failure Stack trace: [org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [SELECT * FROM patient where id =?  ]; SQL state [0A000]; error code [0]; Method org.postgresql.jdbc3.Jdbc3PreparedStatement.setQueryTimeout(int) is not yet implemented.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc3.Jdbc3PreparedStatement.setQueryTimeout(int) is not yet implemented.]
```

Comment: You should insert the error in code block for better lisibility

Answer (score 1):

The error message is clear. It's not yet implemented, so either find a newer driver where it *is* implemented, or if one doesn't exist, don't use that method.

The latest, most advanced driver is the [JDBC42 Postgresql Driver, Version 9.4.1209](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-9.4.1209.jar). If it doesn't work with that, then you just can't use the method.

Seems like [this was an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26550316/hikaricp-with-postgresql-setquerytimeoutint-is-not-yet-implemented) previously and caused by using a test query in the connection pool. In the latest drivers it is implemented, but a test query shouldn't be used anyway because there's the `Connection.isValid()` method that is explicitly meant for testing the validity.

Comment: @user3715296 Guess what that means?

Comment: @user3715296 Which Java version are you using?

Comment: Jdk 1.7 we are using

Comment: Then the driver I linked would not work. It's meant for 1.8. Are you sure you tested it? There's the latest [JDBC41](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html) version for 1.7 too.

Comment: I just checked the sources and `setQueryTimeout()` is implemented. You're not using the correct drivers. You say that you tested the latest ones, but that can't be true. Since you don't know how to use a correct driver, there's very little I can do to help you.

Comment: able to resolve the error Thanks .The problem is in parent it has a different version of driver

Comment: @user3715296, If this answer helped you resolve the issue then you might consider accepting this as an **ANSWER**!